# Displaying data from class array

Tags: java, arrays, json, class

I have problem with displaying data from an array of classes. The data is coming from JSON:

*[{"id":1,"userId":1,"date":"2020-03-02T00:00:02.000Z","products":[{"productId":1,"quantity":4},{"productId":2,"quantity":1},{"productId":3,"quantity":6}],"__v":0},{"id":2,"userId":1,"date":"2020-01-02T00:00:02.000Z","products":[{"productId":2,"quantity":4},{"productId":1,"quantity":10},{"productId":5,"quantity":2}],"__v":0},{"id":3,"userId":2,"date":"2020-03-01T00:00:02.000Z","products":[{"productId":1,"quantity":2},{"productId":9,"quantity":1}],"__v":0},{"id":4,"userId":3,"date":"2020-01-01T00:00:02.000Z","products":[{"productId":1,"quantity":4}],"__v":0},{"id":5,"userId":3,"date":"2020-03-01T00:00:02.000Z","products":[{"productId":7,"quantity":1},{"productId":8,"quantity":1}],"__v":0},{"id":6,"userId":4,"date":"2020-03-01T00:00:02.000Z","products":[{"productId":10,"quantity":2},{"productId":12,"quantity":3}],"__v":0},{"id":6,"userId":8,"date":"2020-03-01T00:00:02.000Z","products":[{"productId":18,"quantity":1}],"__v":0}]*

Screen how it's currently works:
[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl0c9.png)

The array length is ok but i dont know how i can call the productId and quantity for these array correctly, any suggestions?

Cart class:

```
public class Cart {
    int id;
    int userId;
    Date date;
    ProductsCart[] products;
    String __v;

 //getters setters here
}
```

ProductCart class

```
public class ProductsCart {
    int productId;
    int quantity;

    //constructors and getters setters here
}
```

That's part of my main code:

```
List<Cart> carts = mapper.readValue(data3, typeReference2);
                for (Cart c : carts) {
                    System.out.println("\nId: " + c.getId() + 
"\nUser Id: " + c.getUserId() + "\nDate: " + 
c.getDate() + "\nProducts: " + c.getProducts()); <-- here is the problem
                }
```

Comment: `Arrays.toString(c.getProducts())`

Comment: not the right way, output: Products: [modulecart.ProductsCart@18d87d80, modulecart.ProductsCart@618425b5]

Comment: `ProductsCart` should implement `toString`...

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly Products: [ProductsCart{productId=10, quantity=2}, ProductsCart{productId=12, quantity=3}]

Comment: By the way, both `Date` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. For a date, use `LocalDate`. For a moment, use `Instant`.